# Html.BeginForm PUT

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It seems impossible to define PUT when I use Html.BeginForm to submit a form whilst updating an item. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Browsers only support GET and POST for sending forms. You could use AJAX though:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/action',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { param1: 'value1' },
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

And if you want to AJAXify a form submission you may take a look at the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin.

Comment: that's what I used to do in the past (using jquery). did not know that you cannot put a form - should a decent browser not be able to do this if it would be 'restful'/use html correctly or do i talk nonsense?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.NET MVC 2, check Html.HttpMethodOverride method and HttpPutAttribute.

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 also check MVC 2 source code.
HttpRequestExtensions.GetHttpMethodOverride method is very cool!

Answer (score 1):

> ... should a decent browser not be able to do this if it would be 'restful'/use html correctly or do i talk nonsense?

According to the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1), Form element only supports GET and POST.  Technically any browser that allows other verbs would be out of spec.  It looks like [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#form-submission-0) will support other verbs though.

Edit: and it looks like now I can link to both documents.