# aspx: is there anyway to change form from POST to PUT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, post

My current aspx form askes users to input fields into texbox and press submit button. We are thinking of using PUT method that read parameters from the URLs? Any quick solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PUT instead of GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc). The original version of ASP.NET used POSTbacks a lot in the WebForms model which is why you are seeing that behaviour. It is possible to write HttpHandlers or HttpModules which give you more flexibility without requiring ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider "port app over to asp.net mvc" as a quick solution =).

Answer (score 0):

[HTML4 doesn't support PUT method in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449190/html-beginform-put/2449260#2449260).  So using PUT in a form method would generate invalid HTML, and I'm reasonably sure the browser will execute a POST instead of a PUT anyway (at least that's what FF 3.6 did when I tried to change the form method to PUT).

If you want to get information out of the URL, just change the form method to be GET instead of POST.